# Temporary table already exists

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, temp-tables

I have a method where i create a temporary table (i drop it before),

```
 public void CreateTempTable() {

        HibernatePersistenceService persistenceService = (HibernatePersistenceService) getPersistenceService();

        String requete="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable";
persistenceService.getSession().createSQLQuery(requete)
                .executeUpdate();

        String requete2 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable AS SELECT t_lot.etabl_cdn ,count(lot_cdn) as lots_vendus"
                + " FROM t_lot group by t_lot.etabl_cdn";

        persistenceService.getSession().createSQLQuery(requete2)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
```

I call this method several times it works fine but sometimes i have an error after the drop telling me that mytable already exists.I don't understand why because i drop it before creating it again.It's like the drop doesn't finish so the create blocks.
Any help with this issus ? thanks.

Comment: Can this code run in parallel? Do you need some locking/synchronization?

Comment: I guess, this issue of locking. How it behave when you have many connection?

Comment: Why don't you create a random table name using a hash function? The table is temporary anyway. That should prevent you of having conflicting table names in parallel processes.

Comment: Perhaps `getSession()` gets a different session for both commands. Try executing both statements in a single line, separated with semicolon.

Comment: @JimJones does not java keep persistent connection? if so you would eventually fill up disk space with uncontrollable temp tables creation. unless it has `discard temp;`  on connection reuse of course

Comment: @VaoTsun That's a good point. I'm just assuming this table will _die_ after the execution is complete. Of course, alternatively one can either drop the table in the same command right before or after the operation.

Comment: @JimJones yes. and here the OP's question comes - he drops table, but it is not dropped, so either getSession() gets a different session, or calls are async and first command runs after the second

Comment: @VaoTsun yes, I'd also bet in one of those issues. I believe something like this would do the trick `String s = "DROP TABLE x IF EXISTS; CREATE TEMP TABLE x (f INT);`"; but here I'm just guessing :-)

Comment: Laurenz sggested it already, but OP does not respond. I have no experience in java and dont know if that method allows multistring SQL or not

Comment: I've already tried one query drop;create ..it tells me later and randomly after several calls (because it works at the begining) that mytable does not exists when i try to query it after its creation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like multiple instances of the script are running in parallel which is giving you the error.

To solve this, you can create a script that checks if the code is already running or not. If its not running, execute your code. Checking can be done normally using `ps -ef` command.